# How did Dumbledore know that the aurors were on their way before his duel with Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter

Shortly before Dumbledore/Voldemort's duel in the Ministry of Magic atrium, Dumbledore says to Voldemort:

> "It was foolish of you to come here tonight, Tom. The aurors are on their way."
>   *-Dumbledore, Order of the Phoenix (film)*

How did Dumbledore know that the aurors would be on their way? I've theorized that it's because Dumbledore used the floo network to enter, which the Ministry surely would have been monitoring because he was on the run. I'm curious if there's any solid evidence though that suggests how he knew this.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there isn't a canon answer to that; it's not in the book (the quote is though perhaps not exact - don't recall). Can presume he notified them but I don't think it's ever been confirmed. Whether he did notify them or not is also questionable for Fudge threatens him again - and Dumbledore reminds him that a) Harry and Dumbledore were telling the truth; and b) he defeated the aurors once and would be willing to do so again.

Comment: The exact quote appears in the book. _“It was foolish to come here tonight, Tom,” said Dumbledore calmly. “The Aurors are on their way —”_ I always took it to mean that Dumbledore had sent a message to the Aurors, and was merely a bit quicker off the mark.

Comment: A bunch of teenagers and death eaters had just been dueling in the Dept. of Mysteries.  Don't you think the authorities would tend to investigate something like that?

Comment: To be honest, there are already 2-3 aurors in the building, moody(retired)  tonks and shacklebolt (i cant remember if all 3 are there) but police were already on the scene and probably called for back up themselves.

Comment: @Himarm... and then the backup called for backup themselves because it's Voldemort for crying out loud, hence the delay and why Dumbledore arrived first.

Comment: Perhaps is was a lucky bluff?

Answer (score 10):

## Because he sent for them using the Fountain of Magical Brethren.

When Dumbledore first appears on the scene he uses Transformation to bring the Fountain of Magical Brethren to life. The witch traps Bellatrix, the wizard traps Harry, the centaur charges Voldemort and the goblin and house-elf slink off to the side.

> Voldemort raised his wand and another jet of green light streaked at Dumbledore, who turned and was gone in a whirling of his cloak. Next second, he had reappeared behind Voldemort and waved his wand towards the remnants of the fountain. **The other statues sprang to life.** The statue of the witch ran at Bellatrix, who screamed and sent spells streaming uselessly off  its chest, before it dived at her, pinning her to the floor. **Meanwhile, the goblin and the house-elf scuttled towards the fireplaces set along the wall** and the one-armed centaur galloped at Voldemort, who vanished and reappeared beside the pool. The headless statue thrust Harry backwards, away from the fight, as Dumbledore advanced on Voldemort and the golden centaur cantered around them both.
>   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 36, The Only One He Ever Feared)*.</sub>

It's made clear earlier in the book that the fireplaces in the Ministry of Magic Atrium are used for transportation by Floo Powder.

> The walls on each side were panelled in shiny dark wood and had many gilded fireplaces set into them. Every few seconds a witch or wizard would emerge from one of the left-hand fireplaces with a soft *whoosh*. On the right-hand side, short queues were forming before each fireplace, waiting to depart.
>   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 7, The Ministry of Magic)*.</sub>

So the house-elf and the goblin were bewitched by Dumbledore to use the fireplace to transport themselves to Fudge and the Aurors. When the Aurors finally appear we see that the goblin and the house-elf are with them.

> The Atrium was full of people; the floor was reflecting the emerand green flames that had burst into life in all the fireplaces along one wall, and streams of witches and wizards were emerging from them. As Dumbledore pulled him back to his feet, **Harry saw the tiny golden statues of the house-elf and the goblin, leading a stunned-looking Cornelius Fudge forward.**
>   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 36, The Only One He Ever Feared)*.</sub>

The fact that the statues are leading Fudge forwards shows that they were the reason he was there. So Dumbledore knew that the Aurors were on the way because he had literally just summoned them himself.

What Dumbledore bewitched the statues to say in order to sound the alarm isn't clear. It's possible that they simply grabbed Fudge and dragged him over to the Ministry. (It's not part of the answer per se but let's just take a moment to wonder at how insanely talented Dumbledore is that he can pull off a spell *this* complicated in a split second alongside a few other spells).

I think it's clear why Dumbledore did this at this stage. He's able to arrest and tie up the other Death Eaters without breaking a sweat. He didn't need to summon the Aurors immediately for that. It was only when he saw that Voldemort himself had turned up that he sought help. He knew that he'd be able to contain Voldemort but that he wouldn't be able to defeat him and capture him like the others. From that moment on, Dumbledore's aim was to distract Voldemort for long enough to ensure he was still there when Fudge and the Aurors got back - so that they could see that he had returned with their own eyes. The Fountain of Magical Brethren was at hand and Dumbledore chose to make use of it to alert the Aurors. His plan worked perfectly.